# Converting guid to string with entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to pass a GUID as a string over web services, however I've hit a bump in the road. The GUID is stored in SQL Server as a `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` and EF pulls it as a GUID. What I would want to do is in my query do this:

```
var query = myEntities.Foo.Where(q => q.Id== Id)
                .Select(bar =>
                        new Bar()
                            { BString = bar.GUID }
                        );
```

Now, C# throws a build error that you cannot convert `System.Guid` to `string`, so I'd think that you could do this:

```
{ BString = bar.GUID.ToString() }
```

or even

```
{ BString = Convert.ToString(bar.GUID) }
```

But both end with runtime exception:

> There was an exception, it was System.NotSupportedException: LINQ to
>   Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String
>   ToString(System.Object)' method, and this method cannot be translated
>   into a store expression.

So I gather that in both cases, it's not able to figure out a T-SQL equivalent of going from `UniqueIdentifier` to `varchar`.

Is there a way around this besides retrieving the object, then iterating over my return set copying each object to a new object and converting guid->string at that point?

Thanks.

Comment: here's a workaround .Let your bar type has a property that returns its Guid as string then use this property in your Linq queries

Comment: what is the value of query after the lambda statement gets executed..?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Convert it to a string *outside* the query part of the LINQ statement.

```
var query = myEntities.Foo.Where(q => q.Id== Id).Select(r => r.GUID)
  .AsEnumerable()
  .Select(guid =>
    new Bar()
    { BString = guid.ToString() }
  );
```

The `.AsEnumerable()` is the important part: it casts the result from `IQueryable` to `IEnumerable`, having the effect of running any further operations on the client after the database query has been made. (You could also use `.ToArray()` or `.ToList()` in its place.)

Comment: Thanks, I'll work with the second query that you have until I can get a chance to performance test.  Otherwise I might have to swap to something like an sproc like Zruty was mentioning.

Answer (score 0):

If performance isn't a concern, you probably should re-map your GUIDs to strings manually, as you suggested yourself:

```
var query = from entity in myEntities.Foo
            where entity.Id == Id
            select new { GUID = entity.GUID };
var response = from item in query.ToList()
               select new Bar { BString = item.GUID }
```

This is similar to what @Tim Rogers suggests, but explicitly split into two queries.

Another option I come up with is writing a stored procedure that converts GUIDs to strings using the T-SQL's native `convert()` statement. This will work around EF's inability to map GUIDs to strings automatically.

Answer (score -2):

It is now possible to use `new Guid(<your string>);` to convert the string into a Guid instead of converting the Guid into a string.

Comment: How does this answer the question?